# How to find who use these strings?

Tags: static-analysis, strings

When i see function like this, im getting confused, because all the strings i need in this function, but how can i find which functions which this strings?
how can i know the address of the function that using one of these string from the list? thx for helping

```
mov eax, 235h
call sub EAF404
mov ecx, 72D14E45h
mov edx, offset almportSites_e ; "Import Sites"
mov eax, 236h
call sub_EAF404
mov ecx, 4D81D89Eh
mov edx, offset aInAutoModeAllF ; "In Auto-Mode all files are transferred ".
mov eax, 237h
call sub EAF404
mov ecx, ΘC42887BFh
mov edx, offset in Folder "In Folder"
mov eax, 238h
call sub_EAF404
mov ecx, 35086F9Fh
mov edx, offset in Progress ; "In Progress"
mov eax, 239h
call sub EAF404
mov ecx, 5FEC8E4Eh
mov edx, offset loc_EBC568
mov eax, 23Ah
call sub_EAF404
mov ecx, 41Beesceh
mov edx, offset include quick ; "Include Quick Connect sites in History"
mov eax, 23Bh
call sub_EAF404
mov ecx, GF260BBC9h
mov edx, offset a Include The Full ; "Include the following logs"
mov eax, 23Ch
call sub_EAF404
mov ecx, 11B82087h
mov edx, offset alncompleteOrIn ; "Incomplete or Invalid Registration Key"
mov eax, 23Dh
call
sub_EAF404
mov ecx, 6BBB9E69h
mov edx, offset info ; "Info"
```

Comment: Could you show sub_EAF404?

Comment: please remember to post code as a text next time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IDA, you can select the string (e.g. `aImportSites_0`), right click and select `Jump to xref to operand...` (keyboard shortcut -> x) and that will show you where (and which functions) reference this string. (The same thing applies for any other label, like functions name, variables etc.)

[ida_strcluster](https://github.com/Comsecuris/ida_strcluster) is a nice plugin that can help you group the strings by function (among other things)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but there is no xref for the strings, only to this function, and i tried to install the plugin but it wont work for some reason.

Comment: In your case the app (FlashFXP) supports different languages, so the code segment you asked about is initializing the strings by id. I'm assuming English is the embedded default and the rest of the languages are in dlf files somewhere.